# Getting WIndows feature names for ASP.NET Core 6 hosting bundle and url rewrite

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to find the windows feature names if they even exist for ASP.NET Core 6 hosting bundle as well as url rewrite. Wanting to have a system of easily installing them using the install windows feature command on PowerShell.

I have used the following commands to try find the feature names but no avail:

```
Get-WindowsFeature
dism /online /get-features /format:table
```

Any help on saying what they are, how to find them or if they don't exist would be helpul. Also if there is better way to try install those 2 using PowerShell that would also be great.

Thanks :)